# Como funciona um Container?

Tags: servidor-de-aplicação

Como funciona um `container` para servidores de aplicações web, como por exemplo, o Tomcat?

Comment: Nossa, que viagem esse artigo da wikipedia, hein. Fala de container em OOP e cita como exemplo um servidor de aplicativos! "Container" em OOP pelo que eu sei é simplesmente uma lista ou algo que o valha (como um array). Não é um termo muito utilizado em OOP porque falar "lista" é mais simples e óbvio. Container enquanto servidor de aplicativo (como o "Tomcat" citado com exemplo na wikipedia) é outro campo, nada a ver com OOP.

Comment: Então, como posso reformular minha pergunta? Qual é o verdadeiro campo do Container?

Comment: Se você quer falar de Tomcat e afins, remova a tag "orientação a objetos". Talvez você deva lançar uma tag como "servidor de aplicativos". Agora, se você quer mesmo falar de OOP, deixe a tag e reafirme isso. Mas daí a resposta não vai muito além do meu comentário (só vamos acrescentar algumas palavras mais abstratas pra definir o conceito num nível mais alto de abstração - mas vamos sempre terminar em "listas" ou "arrays" hehe).

Comment: Ok @Caffé, obrigado pela dica, acabei de reformular a pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

## O que é um container

Neste caso, chamamos de **container** aquilo que oferecerá suporte para o nosso aplicativo rodar.

Ou seja, nosso aplicativo não tem código suficiente para rodar sozinho, ele precisa de alguém que o carregue na memória, receba requisições e direcione para ele estas requisições.

Estes containers **geralmente são servidores de aplicativos**.

Mesmo quando o container de fato é um servidor de aplicativos, ele também pode atuar em alguns cenários de maneira "embarcada" em vez de atuar como um serviço, por exemplo.

## E o que é um servidor de aplicativos

> Um servidor de aplicativos como o *Tomcat* (e podemos citar outros exemplos como *GlasFish*, *WebSphere*, *JBoss*, *IIS*, etc), é um sistema especilizado em suportar aplicações consumidas remotamente.

Geralmente eles estão associados a *"aplicações web"*, embora não raramente estas aplicações sejam acessadas apenas através de uma rede privada.

Estes servidores de aplicativos sozinho não fazem nada importante. A função deles é diponibilizar para consumo um aplicativo específico que atende necessidades específicas.

## Como um servidor de aplicativos oferece suporte a um aplicativo web?

A rigor, você não precisa de um servidor de aplicativos para rodar o seu aplicativo web.

Veja: você pode escrever um código que escute requisições **TCP/IP** numa porta específica do servidor, inteprete estas requisições segundo o protocolo **HTTP**, execute o processamento determinado pela **mensagem** HTTP, e devolva uma **resposta** numa outra mensagem HTTP.

Você também pode querer adicionar código para tratar log, balanceamento de carga, cache, pool de conexões com banco de dados, segurança, criptografia... Depois de implementar tudo isso você terá feito o seu próprio servidor de aplicativos para atender um aplicativo em particular.

E para isso servem os servidores de aplicativo: oferecer soluções padrão que serão requeridas por muitos diferentes aplicativos web.

## Um exemplo

Considere um aplicativo web feito em **Java** e que implementa **Servlets**.

A função básica do servidor de aplicativos, neste caso, é carregar esse aplicativo em memória, receber requisições remotas e direcionar cada requisição para o Servlet responsável por atendê-la segundo configurações do aplicativo que o servidor de aplicativos lê e respeita.

Quando o seu Servlet disponibilizar uma resposta, o servidor de aplicativos devolve esta resposta pela mesma porta em resposta à aquela requisição.

Answer (score 3):

Brother, a questão é a especificação para rodar sua aplicação.
por exemplo, se vc seguir a especificação JEE - estandard edition, ela possui 2 tipos de servidores que suportam vários tipos de tecnologias neste caso(sua pergunta) WebContainer e EJB Container. 
Como uso WebContainer, irei falar sobre ele. 
No caso o do TomCat, ele é um webcontainer simples ou enxuto, para gerenciar aplicações web, desenvolvidas em JSF, JSP servlets(especificações que estão contidas na JEE).
A forma de funcionamento seria exemplificada por uma comparação:
Imagine um browser fazendo requisições(request) de páginas estáticas(HTML) à um servidor, ele por sua vez devolverá uma resposta(response), no caso a página em questão. Com o webcontainer gerenciando a aplicação ele irá formatar a resposta dinamicamente e devolverá um conteúdo exclusivo ao cliente.
em relação a sua tag, ela não está completamente correta, pois um servidor de aplicações é mais completo, ele não é apenas um webcontainer ou apenas um EJB container, ele é os dois, além de várias outras coisas. 
Exemplo de servidores de aplicações: GlasFish e JBoss.